# Sum IF Count Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

rows 3-4 generate 2 data (1,1), because generating more than 1 row must be sum, how to sum it

```
SELECT  
    t1.kel_id AS 'id'
  , (SELECT IF(COUNT(a1.id)>500,1,0) 
     FROM dp_aktif a1 
     LEFT JOIN tps_local a2 
            ON a1.tps_id = a2.tps_id 
     WHERE a1.kel_id=t2.id 
     GROUP BY a1.tps_id) as total 
FROM dp_aktif t1 
LEFT JOIN wilayah_local t2 
       ON t1.kel_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.status != 'tms' 
  AND t1.kec_id = 25834 
GROUP BY t1.kel_id
```

[image]

Comment: please dont include images. Also pelase add sample data and expected output

Comment: please add some sample data for each table used by the query, the table schemas, relationships & expected results given the sample data

Comment: Its not at all clear what result is supposed to be returned, given what data. Without a specification, we have no way of determining whether any SQL construct will be satisfactory, i.e. returns a resultset that complies with the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Select COUNT as you're selecting "Jumlah TPS" and set the condition (> x) in your "where" clause.